# CMake build only subprojects, but not top-level project

Tags: c++, cmake, building, subproject

There is top-level project named 'cppserial', which depends on subproject 'cppstreams', which also depends on subproject 'cpputils'.
The file structure of whole project:

```
cppserial/
  |
  CMakeLists.txt
  src/
    |
    cppserial/
      source files
  libs/
    |
    cppstreams/
      |
      CMakeLists.txt
      libs/
        |
        cpputils/
          |
          CMakeLists.txt
          src/
            |
            cpputils/
              source files
      src/
        |
        cppstreams/
          source files
```

cppserial CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(cppserial)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(SOURCE  ...sources...)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${SOURCE})

add_subdirectory(libs/cppstreams)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC cppstreams)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
```

cppstreams CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(cppstreams)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(SOURCES ...sources...)
set(HEADERS ...headers...)

set(BOOST_ROOT D:/Development/CXX/Libraries/Boost)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON) 
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)  
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})

add_subdirectory(libs/cpputils)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC cpputils)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
```

cpputils CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(cpputils)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(SOURCES ...sources...)
set(HEADERS ...headers...)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
```

Building:

```
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

Build output:

```
[main] Configuring folder: cppserial 
[proc] Executing command: D:\Software\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -Sd:/Development/CXX/cppserial -Bd:/Development/CXX/cppserial/build -G "Visual Studio 17 2022"
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.33.31630.0
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.33.31630.0
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: D:/Software/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.33.31629/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Software/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.33.31629/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] -- Found Boost: D:/Development/CXX/Libraries/Boost/lib/cmake/Boost-1.80.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.80.0")  
[cmake] -- Configuring done
[cmake] -- Generating done
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: D:/Development/CXX/cppserial/build
[visual-studio] Patch Windows SDK path from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64 to C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64 for D:\Software\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat
```

Compiling output:

```
MSBuild version 17.3.1+2badb37d1 for .NET Framework
  Checking Build System
  Building Custom Rule D:/Development/CXX/cppserial/libs/cppstreams/libs/cpputils/CMakeLists.txt
  ...source files...
  cpputils.vcxproj -> D:\Development\CXX\cppserial\build\libs\cppstreams\libs\cpputils\Debug\cpputils.lib
  Building Custom Rule D:/Development/CXX/cppserial/libs/cppstreams/CMakeLists.txt
  ...source files...
  cppstreams.vcxproj -> D:\Development\CXX\cppserial\build\libs\cppstreams\Debug\cppstreams.lib
  Building Custom Rule D:/Development/CXX/cppserial/CMakeLists.txt
  Building Custom Rule D:/Development/CXX/cppserial/CMakeLists.txt
```

As you can see, only subprojects are being built. There is no cppserial.lib in the build folder.
I can't understand what could i miss.

Comment: What are the sources for the top level project?

Comment: Note also, that setting variables like `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` **after** the `find_package(Boost)` is **useless**: these variables are read only during that `find_package` call.

Comment: @local-ninja there are two *.h files in SOURCES list of top-level project. There are also problems with them: #include can't find include directories of subprojects (cppstreams, cpputils). I thought this trouble is an effect of current topic problem, but i have doubts.

Comment: Also, despite specifying `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20` and `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON` in the CMakeLists.txt of the top-level project, features of C++ 20 are not available, though headers are available, for example, <concepts> is available, it's found, but compiler says that keyword `concept` is undefined.

Comment: If there's nothing to compile, then nothing will be built (it's a header-only library). You can use the top-level library in cmake as a dependency, the linker will only link against all transitive dependencies. Everything just as expected. The c++20 problem is another issue, your scripts look fine. Do you want to use concepts in another downstream project? In this case you have to set `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` there as well.

Comment: @local-ninja For the C++ standard `target_compile_features(... INTERFACE cxx_std_20)` should be used; this avoids the possibility of linking targets breaking, since if you forget to set the variable; furthermore in the future this allows you to e.g. set the exact standard to use to 23 for the whole project via cache entry without modification (the compile feature just specifies the minimal C++ standard).

Comment: @local-ninja okay, now it's clear for me that there is nothing to build. Also, i found out that if i add some cpp file to the top-level project , the problem with include directories disappears, even if this cpp file is absolutely empty. How should i do? I don't need any .cpp file in project, but then the problem with include dirs remains, `#include`'s are underlined in IDE and it says "not found". I'm literally confused.

Comment: One header file of the top-level project is interface declaration like Serializable, it doesn't have any implementation. Second header file is helper class with static template methods, so this header also doesn't need .cpp file.